# Determine type of disk on Windows with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I want to list all of my disk and can be able to know its type: "SATA" "NVME" "M.2" or "PCI" on Windows computer.

I made some research with wmi and I get the interface (SCSI or IDE):

```
c = wmi.WMI()
for disk in c.Win32_DiskDrive():
    print(disk.InterfaceType)
```

But I don't get the type of the disk. Maybe with the interface I can get the type of my disk ?

Do you have any idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Query the [`MSFT_PhysicalDisk` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-physicaldisk) if you insist upon `wmi`:

```
import wmi
ws = wmi.WMI(namespace='root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage')
for d in ws.MSFT_PhysicalDisk():
    print(d.BusType, d.MediaType, d.Model)
```

**Sample ouput**

> ```
>  7 3 Elements 1078
> 11 4 KINGSTON model
> 11 3 WDC another model
> ```

`MediaType` enumeration:

```
Value   Meaning
0       Unspecified
3       HDD
4       SSD
5       SCM
```

Newest `BusType` enumeration (from [WMI Explorer 2.0.0.2](https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/wiki)):

```
Value Text                Meaning
----- ----                -------
0     Unknown             The bus type is unknown.
1     SCSI                SCSI
2     ATAPI               ATAPI
3     ATA                 ATA
4     1394                IEEE 1394
5     SSA                 SSA
6     Fibre Channel       Fibre Channel
7     USB                 USB
8     RAID                RAID
9     ISCSI               iSCSI
10    SAS                 Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
11    SATA                Serial ATA (SATA)
12    SD                  Secure Digital (SD)
13    MMC                 Multimedia Card (MMC)
14    MAX                 This value is reserved for system use.
15    File Backed Virtual File-Backed Virtual
16    Storage Spaces      Storage Spaces
17    NVMe                NVME
18    SCM                 SCM
19    UFS                 UFS
20    reserved            Microsoft reserved
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But when i execute your code I get RAID for my 2 disk and one of them is NVMe... What is exactly RAID ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you are looking for

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', 'Get-PhysicalDisk | ft -AutoSize DeviceId,Model,MediaType,BusType,Size'], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
    universal_newlines=True)

print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: If you can rely on 3.7+ (hopefully you can, 3.7 is the oldest version still getting support of any kind), you can simplify the arguments significantly, replacing `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True` with `capture_output=True, text=True`. That said, not a fan of farming out work to `subprocess` when it's at *all* possible to avoid it and use in-Python APIs to query programmatically; it's more opaque when things go wrong, relies on PowerShell existing/not being corrupted (that happened to me somehow a couple months ago, had a hell of a time fixing it), etc.